# Fail to assign *IO() object to WRITEDATA, pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

Anyone else noticed that the pycurl example doesn't work on Python 2.*?

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a string in some encoding.
# In Python 2, we can print it without knowing what the encoding is.
print(body)
```

Then I get a failure like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_python2.py", line 9, in <module>
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt
```

Assigning WRITEFUNCTION & others seem to function as advertised. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 10):

I think the [docs](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html) kind of indicate you have to use `WRITEFUNCTION` when you don't have a true file object:

> On Python 3 and on Python 2 when the value is not a true file object, WRITEDATA is emulated in PycURL via WRITEFUNCTION.

So you'd need to use:

```
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
```

**Edit:**

The [PycURL Quickstart](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html) uses WRITEDATA as an example with StringIO, but it requires PycURL >= version 7.19.3:

> As of PycURL 7.19.3 WRITEDATA accepts any Python object with a write method

Comment: I guess this is it. But this example is taken from PyCURL Quick Start... . Anyways, thanks for pointing this out, have an upvote!

Comment: @user1906583: Interesting...which versions of PycURL & Python are you using?

Comment: Someone wants to debug? I'm using Python 2.7.8 on Cygwin, installed from Cygwin's package mangement-thingy. Then I just downloaded pycurl 7.19.5 using "python setup.py install". The above example comes from http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html, first block of code. BTW you were right, c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write) works if I instantiate buffer = BytesIO().

Comment: @user1906583:  The reason I ask is that your example works for me (no exceptions).  Maybe you've installed pycurl in a different python instance than what you're actually running.  If you print out `pycurl.version` in your program, does it show that version (7.19.5)?

Comment: hello Gerrat. Here's a string that returned "'libcurl/7.39.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.2'". So it seems like I'm using older than 7.19.3 of pycurl. This means my "python setup.py install" didn't work properly. Too bad I didn't keep a log of this install. But good to know that I have a much deeper problem now!

Answer (score 1):

Try
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)

I had exactly the same problem and it worked this way.
pycurl (7.19.0)